# What is Twitter.rs ? Is it the same as Twitter.com?

Tags: twitter

I accidentally came across [twitter.rs](http://twitter.rs) while googling. Is it the same as twitter.com? What is the purpose of it? What does `.rs` stand for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.rs` is the Top Level Domain for [Serbia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.rs).

Performing a trace route on both the `Twitter.com` & `Twitter.rs` domains both resolve to the same IP schema and the same domain.

Domain: `xe-10-0-0.smf1-er2.twttr.com`

IP: 199.16.159.53

I can only imagine that Twitter have registered the domain as a play on words for "Twitterers" and/or "Twitters" or something of that ilk.